# No More Confusing Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings

Following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     char a[10]="Hi!";  
    void f(char b[])
    {
        // 1. printf("*a is:%s\n",*a);
        printf("&a is:%p\n",&a);
        // 2. printf("&&a is:%p\n",&(&a));
        printf("a's address is:%p\n",a);
        printf("a's value is:%s\n",a);
        printf("b's address is:%p\n",b);
        printf("b's value is:%s\n",b);
        // 3. printf("*b is:%s\n",*b);
        printf("&b is:%s\n",&b);
    }

    f(a);

    return 1;
    getch();
}
```

Running the above code gives the output:

```
&a is:0028FF1C
a's address is:0028FF1C
a's value is:Hi!
b's address is:0028FF1C
b's value is:Hi!
&b is:∟ (
```

In the Output:
    Why are there different outputs for `&a` and `&b`;
    Although a and b have same reference.

Further,

I've mentioned 3 comments by their number.
If I remove slashes one by one and execute them,I get following 2 issues:

1. On executing comment no. 1 & 3:

   ```
   "abc.exe has stopped working."
   ```
2. On executing comment no. 2:

   ```
   abc.c: In function 'f':
   abc.c:14:32: error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
             printf("&&a is:%p\n",&(&a));
                           ^
   ```

Comment: Too many questions. But `a` and `b` are not the same object, so their address is different.

Comment: No the address is same,see the output.

Comment: There's no place in your code where you're successfully printing out the address of `b`.

Comment: Fix the format code in the &b printf (change to %p) and edit your post with the new result.

Comment: @Napa Do not edit the "solution" into your question.  Instead upvote/accept helpful answer and/or answer your own question with those details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Point 1:** **[Nested functions are not standard `C`. They are supported as GCC extension.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)**.
- **Point 2:** `printf("&b is:%s\n",&b);` is wrong and invokes UB, because of improper format specifier. You need to change that to

  ```
   printf("&b is:%p\n",(void *)&b);
  ```
- **Point 3:** `&(&a)` is wrong. the operand for `&` needs to be an lvalue, not another *address*, which is not an lvalue.

  Related: `C11`, chapter `§6.5.3.2`, for the operand type

  > The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the register storage-class specifier.

  and the return type

  > ....result is not an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

You copy pasted the `printf()` and didn't change the specifier

```
printf("&b is:%s\n", &b)
/*             ^ should be `p' */
```

The first comment, when executed is causing a problem because you are using the `"%s"` specifier and passing the first character of `a` which will be interpreted as an address, try this

```
printf("*a is: %c\n", *a);
```

The third comment presents the same problem.

The second comment, you need an intermidiate pointer to do that, like

```
char  *c = &a;
char **d = &c;

printf("%p\n", (void *) d);
```

although it will print the same as `printf("%p\n", (void *) a);` because they all have the same address, the differenece is that the pointer arithmetic will work different.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you shouldn't define functions inside another function - though some compilers accept that (like `gcc`), it isn't portable.

```
    printf("&b is:%s\n",&b);
```

Here `&b` is the address of `b`, which is the address of the char array. In effect &b is the address of the parameter.

1.) and 3.) fail because you need to pass a pointer to a string. *a, is a dereferenced pointer, so, in effect, it's the first character of the string

2.) &&a is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer (as `a` *is* already a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is the question author's own answer, see [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31164578/revisions)

---

I understood the above issues and here's the improved code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int i;


    char a[11]="F*** Yeahh!";  //String : char *

    //'a' gets memory in "globals" area;'a' is a pointer to 'F'

    void func();//Function Definition

    int main()
    {
        func(a);    //Passing reference of 'a' to func
        getch();
        return 1;
    }

    void func(char b[])
        //'b' is given memory in 'stack' region;'b' has a reference
        // to 'a'   which in turn refer to 'F'
    {
        printf("*a is:%c\n",*a);
        printf("&a is:%p\n",&a);

        //printf("&&a is:%p\n",&(&a));//&()...Inside braces,there must be a
        // value..

        printf("a's address is:%p\n",a);
        printf("a's value is:%s\n",a);
        printf("b's address is:%p\n",b);
        printf("b's value is:%s\n",b);
        printf("*b is:%c\n",*b);
        printf("&b is:%p\n",&b);

        for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
            printf("String as an array of characters is:%c\n",b[i]);
    }
```

Here's The Output:

```
*a is:F
&a is:00409000
a's address is:00409000
a's value is:F*** Yeahh!
b's address is:00409000
b's value is:F*** Yeahh!
*b is:F
&b is:0028FF20
String as an array of characters is:F
String as an array of characters is:*
String as an array of characters is:*
String as an array of characters is:*
String as an array of characters is:
String as an array of characters is:Y
String as an array of characters is:e
String as an array of characters is:a
String as an array of characters is:h
String as an array of characters is:h
String as an array of characters is:!
```